# Get RCW's from Marshal to see which object is being held

Tags: c#, com, vsto, interop, excel-dna

I have an Excel add-in that needs a lot of long running references to Excel native objects. Every now and then when a user closes Excel it 'hangs' keeping an Excel process live in the background.

There's quite been some debate between [trusting the GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904483/as-of-today-what-is-the-right-way-to-work-with-com-objects) and [doing manual cleanup](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2020/07/20/releasing-com-objects-garbage-collector-marshal-relseasecomobject/). Orignially I trusted the GC, also doing this when the add-in unloads for good measure:

```
do {
    GC.Collect();
    GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
}
while (Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup());
```

but now the issue keeps popping up at random and I'm finding it hard to figure out what it could be. Also inserted `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` everywhere but every now and then it still hangs.

So I was thinking, if I can ask `Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup` then apparently there's a central list of RCW's being kept by `Marshal`?

Is there a way to get to this list and display information about the native objects being held? That would be really helpful in finding the offender.
I looked over the [public methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal?view=netframework-4.8) but there does not seem to be anything available. [Looking at the source](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs#L1958) the trail goes dead at this call:

```
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[MethodImplAttribute(MethodImplOptions.InternalCall)]
internal static extern int InternalReleaseComObject(Object o);
```

But maybe someone here knows a way to continue and list the objects?

Any other suggestions to get Excel to shut down properly also welcome of course.

Comment: The problem is really neither a pure COM nor a .NET/RCW issue, everything is properly done by .NET and the GC (first link). The difficult here is you're talking to an out-of-process COM server (an .EXE) which basically can live its own, show UI, etc. if it wants to and there's nothing "smart" you can do against it. If your issue is to make sure no Excel.exe process keeps living, you could try to terminate them. These processes are started with "/automation -Embedding" in the command line, and their parent should be svchost.exe (DComLaunch aka "DCOM Server Process Launcher" service)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53001928/difference-between-sos-rcw-and-sos-dumprcw-output

Comment: @SimonMourier yeah that was a fallback plan, just call Environment.Exit(0)) after a timer has expired to allow it to try to shutdown on it's own first. Maybe a bit crude but it might get the job done.

Comment: @HansPassant ah interesting, seems like a bit of homework to wrap my head around but I could run this on my box if it does hang there. Thx.

Comment: Here is a (undocumented) trick to get exact Excel process id if things went wrong: https://pastebin.com/raw/ZtEbmfBJ

Comment: For an in-process Excel add-in, it is crucial that you only access the COM object model from the main Excel thread (ManagedId == 1). If you try any kind of access from another thread, task, async method, message or network callback, you end up in the bad place eventually. Excel-DNA has a helper called `ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro` that lets you run code on the main thread again - this is safe to call any time from any thread. Then do your COM stuff inside the macro / delegate which runs on the main thread. If you follow this rule, you need not invoke the GC for cleanup and Excel closes OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Excel crashing after being closed and for me it was also related to COM Objects not being released properly on shutdown.

I have followed Goverts suggestion to use the OnDisconnection (here using the Ribbon deriving from ExcelComAddIn which implents IDTExtensibility2) method (Functions.StatusCollection and DBModifDefColl are collections of dynamically allocated objects containing references to excel ranges, which are then explicitly released using Marshal.ReleaseComObject):

```
Public Class MenuHandler
  Inherits CustomUI.ExcelRibbon

  Public Overrides Sub OnDisconnection(RemoveMode As ExcelDna.Integration.Extensibility.ext_DisconnectMode, ByRef custom As Array)
    For Each aKey As String In Functions.StatusCollection.Keys
        Dim clearRange As Excel.Range = Functions.StatusCollection(aKey).formulaRange
        If Not IsNothing(clearRange) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(clearRange)
    Next
    For Each DBmodifType As String In DBModifDefColl.Keys
        For Each dbmapdefkey As String In DBModifDefColl(DBmodifType).Keys
            Dim clearRange As Excel.Range = DBModifDefColl(DBmodifType).Item(dbmapdefkey).getTargetRange()
            If Not IsNothing(clearRange) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(clearRange)
        Next
    Next
    Do
        GC.Collect()
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()
    Loop While (Marshal.AreComObjectsAvailableForCleanup())
  End Sub
...
```

Once this was implemented I had no more crashes on excel shutdown...

Comment: Interesting, will have a good look. It doesn't happen that often anymore but still would be great to eliminate completely.